# Issue with ingest values, 2x more

Tags: python, data-ingestion, mlops, feature-store, mlrun

When I ingested values to the feature set, the pipeline was called 2x more (I used MLRun version 1.2.1). It seems as the issue, do you know why?

I used this code:

```
import mlrun
import mlrun.feature_store as fstore

# mlrun: start-code
import math

def calc(x):
    x['fn2']=math.sin(x['fn2'])*100.0
    print('calc')
    return x

# mlrun: end-code

mlrun.set_env_from_file("mlrun-nonprod.env")
project = mlrun.get_or_create_project(project_name, context='./', user_project=False)
feature_derived = fstore.get_feature_set(f"{project_name}/{feature_derivedName}")
...
# dataFrm has only two values
feature_derived.graph.to(name="calc", handler='calc')
fstore.ingest(feature_derived, dataFrm)
```

I got this output (method `calc` was called four times) for dataFrm with two values:

```
> calc
> calc 
> calc
> calc
```

Comment: Can you please set the online and offline targets and try your code again?

Comment: @xsqian, see #2729

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easy, it is enough to switch-off preview mode based on setting `infer_options=0` in ingest method. See part of the code

```
...
feature_derived.graph.to(name="calc", handler='calc')
fstore.ingest(feature_derived, dataFrm, infer_options=0)
...
```

The output has only two values (as requested):

```
> calc
> calc
```